# you roll a 6 sided die what is your P(prime)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

you roll a 6 sided die. whqat is P(prime)? write your answer as a percentage

Comment: **Hint:** The six numbers on a fair six-sided die are traditionally $1,2,3,4,5,6$.  The sequence of primes begins $2,3,5,7,11,13,\dots$

Answer (score 2):

Well, between $1$ and $6$, there are $3$ primes ($2, 3, 5$), so the chances of you getting a prime number with a $6$ sided die is:

You work out the rest!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I applaud your wanting to help by providing this correct answer. But I would rather you hadn't - it's better to ask the OP to show some work of their own before providing a full solution.

Comment: Yes apologies for that, I have edited my answer to let the OP work it out for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to work out what outcomes of your die would be prime. Then you can express this as a fraction out of 6 (because there are 6 possible numbers the die could give).

Then you need to turn it into a percentage. You can do this by turning the fraction into a decimal then multiplying by 100.